# How to test client validation in a form input with angular and bootstrap?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, validation, input, jasmine

I'm trying to test the required attribute on this markup

```
<div id="div_formDeviceName" class="form-group was-validated"        [ngClass]="{'has-error': !isNameUnique || !(myName.valid || myName.pristine)}">
      <label id="lbl_deviceName" >Name *</label>
      <input id="in_deviceName" name="in_alias" #myName="ngModel" maxlength="255" [(ngModel)]="device.name" (blur)="trimName($event)" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback text-danger" id="div_deviceRequired"
           *ngIf="(myName.errors && myName.errors.required)" translate>Required
      </div>
</div>
```

So if the user deletes the name in the input field, the error message will be shown.

This works fine and i would like to test it.

```
it("client error validation", async(() => {
    component.device = new Device();
    component.device.name = "My unit test device";
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const deviceName: DebugElement = 
      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#in_deviceName"));
    const input: HTMLInputElement = deviceName.nativeElement;

    console.debug(input.value);
    expect(input.attributes
      .getNamedItem("ng-reflect model").value)
        .toBe(component.device.name);
    input.value = "";
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {    
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const divError: DebugElement = 
        fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#div_deviceRequired"));
      const divErrRequired: HTMLInputElement = divError.nativeElement;

      expect(divErrRequired).toBeDefined();
    });
```

But the input value in the test never changes and div query fails...